# Laravel Cache, is requerying a cached query

Tags: laravel, caching

i have the following code: it is cached but is re-queried (shows up in the debugbar) for each request. tried redis, memcached,database on local homestead

```
$system_api_token = \Cache::remember('system_api_token_master', 25,function ()  {

      return User::GetApiToken(2);

         });

 return $system_api_token;
```

Comment: What Laravel is this?

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.4

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It seems that you call `User::GetApiToken(2)` multiple times, not just in the closure above.

Comment: I call it it only once, Where do you see it called once more? the return was to execute the debugbar. I want the token set to that var.

Comment: I mean elsewhere in the code, I can't see your code so, I can not speculate any further. Still no idea what you want to achieve.